# Is it possible to drag window/view out of workbench in an e4 application written in pure JavaFX?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, eclipse-rcp, efxclipse

I have an e4 application written in pure JavaFX, which you can see from my screenshot below.
[image]

I have two tabs, **Test** and **ButtonView**, I can drag and drop any of them in the main application window. However I find that I can't drag any of them out of the main window (or should it be called **workbench** in Eclipse application). So I'm wondering is there a way to make dragging window/view out of the main application window/workbench possible if I'm using pure JavaFX developing an e4 application?

Answer (score 0):

You want to "detach" your view. I hope the [following article](https://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2012/07/13/so-you-used-internal-api/) helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround from e(fx)clipse forum [here](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=rview&goto=1750785#msg_1750785). It is not supported in current release of e(fx)clipse (**v2.4.0**). We can achieve this by appending `-Ddetachdrag.enabled=true` to the VM parameter if we use the the latest nightly from head though.